# Mixing JS and PHP variables

Tags: javascript, php, mediawiki

I'm using MediaWiki and looking to have a different Google Analytics tag load for each wiki dependent on the database name. I'm struggling with how to do this, however, given the GA tag uses JavaScript and the array/variable I'm using is in PHP.

This is what I have thus far (the correct key => value will already be chosen by the script earlier based on the database name, so I don't have to worry about that):

```
 $wgAnalyticsCode => [
   'wiki1' => '(code 1)',
   'wiki2' => '(code 2)',
   'wiki3' => '(code 3)'
 ]
```

and then I have the hook that runs before the page loads and adds the tag (which is a mix of PHP/JavaScript:

```
$wgHooks['BeforePageDisplay'][] = function( OutputPage &$out, Skin &$skin ) {
     $code = <<<HTML
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=CODEHERE"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'CODEHERE');
</script>
HTML;

     $out->addHeadItem( 'gtag-insert', $code );
     return true;
};
```

I'm not entirely sure how to get the tag from the PHP array into the JavaScript? Usually, if it was just JavaScript, I would replace "CODEHERE" with `$wgAnalyticsCode`, but obviously it isn't that easy given that the variable is PHP and the code is JavaScript.

Any advice would be appreciated?

Comment: you can use ajax to call to PHP and get the tags in json format and then utilize it JS

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `use` word to pass your array to the anonymous function

Example

```
$wgHooks['BeforePageDisplay'][] = function (OutputPage &$out, Skin &$skin) use ($wgAnalyticsCode) {
```

after that you can use your array inside the function body

i hope it's helpful

Comment: Like so? As it doesn't seem to work, the tag just comes empty without a ID. https://pastebin.com/fnYTkhcZ

Comment: yes, you can now use it inside the function, but you cant just print it because its an array, it should be like this `{$wgAnalyticsCode['wiki1']}` or `{$wgAnalyticsCode['wiki2']}` ... etc